# Trouble with script src attribute in Geddy application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, src, geddy

I am new to Geddy and I am having trouble getting the HTML script tag to pull in external .js files. My file hierarchy looks like this:

- Application

  - Models
  - Controllers
  - Views
  - ExternalJS

    - file.js

In one of my views, I would like to include file.js, so I have this in it's html file:

```
<script src='/ExternalJS/file.js'></script>
```

However, this doesn't actually work at pulling the file in. I suspect it has something to do with Geddy's router. As of now, going to

```
https://localhost/ExternalJS/file.js
```

results in a 404 because the router cannot match that route to a controller/action pair.

I would very much like to keep the ExternalJS folder where it is; I will need to add to it in the future. So what do I do to fix this issue? Is it a routing problem, some dumb mistake with src, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to keep that folder where it is, and not in the `public` directory, you'll need to write a few routes and a static file handler for it.

Your route should look something like this (this is off the top of my head, not tested)

```
router.get('ExternalJS/:file(.:format)').to('Main.externaljs')
```

Then in your `main.js` controller you'd need to do something like this:

```
this.externaljs = function (req, res, params) {
  // serve up the file from disk or cache or something
}
```